# ampy runs into an errror, ab ttyUSB0 is after then never available, till replugin the USB wire

Tags: ubuntu, usb, tty

On Ubuntu 20.04 it works very well, but after the upgrad to 22.04 it runs into an error.

You can see it in the screen image.

Plug in --> `ttyUSB0` is available

Run a ampy command --> "`failed to access`"

And than `ttyUSB0` is never available, till replugin the USB wire.

My User is int the dailout group.

If i run it as sudo or normal user the error comes up.

Also if i set up the `--boud` to `11520`

What kind of config could be missen?

[image]